# What is the origin of the kinetic theory of temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, specific-reference, history

Count Rumford's experiments with canon barrels are often cited here, but the kinetic theory certainly precedes them. Another candidate is Daniel Bernoulli, who, in his 1738 book Hydrodynamica showed how Boyle's law follows from the kinetic model. But Bernoulli writes, "As it is well known that heat is intensified as the internal motion of the particles increases..." indicating that these ideas were already current when he wrote. Does anyone have an earlier reference?

Comment: Well, the early history of the kinetic origin of *heat* is discussed in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_heat .